# Convert Varchar to Float from a variable string and insert into SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. I have created a script where I import data and insert into SQL Server. The update query works fine but the insert query does not . I get a error

> Error converting data type varchar to float.. INSERT INTO dbo.

This is the code

```
 $amount = trim(str_replace('$','',$data[2]));
// echo ($amount); // prints 1,000,000.00

// INSERT QUERY
//Try 1 : Fails

  $Query  = "INSERT INTO dbo.testtable (id, name, amount) 
                                values ( 11, 'John' , $amount )";

  //Try 2 : Fails

  $Query  = "INSERT INTO dbo.testtable (id, name, amount) 
                                values ( 11, 'John' ,  CONVERT(FLOAT,'$amount') )";
```

How in the world can I insert a proper float value from the variable (`$amount`) into SQL Server?

Comment: you need to remove the commas from the $amount

Comment: there is no comma, u mean single quotes? i did but no change.Still error :CONVERT(FLOAT,$amount) -->[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','..

Comment: **"echo ($amount); // prints 1,000,000.00"** i see 2 commas

Comment: oh i understand now what u mean

Comment: exactly, it has comas

Comment: i have the magic power of reading ;-)

Comment: using this function to remove , function Getfloat($str) { 
  if(strstr($str, ",")) { 
    $str = str_replace(".", "", $str); // replace dots (thousand seps) with blancs 
    $str = str_replace(",", ".", $str); // replace ',' with '.' 
  } 
  
  if(preg_match("#([0-9\.]+)#", $str, $match)) { // search for number that may contain '.' 
    return floatval($match[0]); 
  } else { 
    return floatval($str); // take some last chances with floatval 
  } 
}     return nothing but 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
cast('$amount' as money)
```

Updates:
It actually depends on what's the type of your column `amount`. If it's varchar, it should not throw an error for 1st line. So, I guess it's something like `decimal(18, 2)`. Refer to the demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/34924)

```
declare @amount varchar(25)
SET @amount = '1,000.00'

create table #tmp_money (amount FLOAT)
insert into #tmp_money
SELECT cast(@amount as money)

select * from #tmp_money
```

Comment: its of type float in db

Comment: I think my answer works for `FLOAT`. You could check the demo link above.

Comment: i am not sure where r u asking me to declare @amount varchar(25)? in the php code?

Comment: No, simply change `CONVERT(FLOAT,'$amount') ` to `cast(@amount as money)`. The link I post above is for testing purpose to demo why my suggestion works.

Comment: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@amount".. INSERT INTO dbo.

Comment: Oops, typo. It should be `CAST('$amount' as money)`.

Comment: i am not getting error but when i echo out the query i get this for the value --->  cast('1,000,000.00' as money),

Comment: You could double check DB to see if it's inserted.

Comment: yeap it works.. its gettting inserted. Thanks. Will this also take care of the decimal? I mean lets say suppose the amount was 10000.42 ? The nwill this work?

Comment: It should work, too. But 10000.42222 will be truncated as 10000.4222.